# How to make jmeter behave like a browser

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm new to JMeter and I've already read some guidelines and all. Now i wanna focus on making my JMeter behave more like a browser. I've already set up everything according to [this guide](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), but I'd like to know if there are any more advanced settings I could apply. Haven't found anything else so far. I'm greatful for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can run jmeter in java code and use html in response to open in browser using [desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)